# Does low android storage affect app's performance?

Tags: android, memory, storage

Good day.i wanted to know if android storage low,does it affect an app performance?Because same app is fast on another device and same is pretty much lagging on another one which has like 2GB of free memory from 12GB of memory.So they both on same device and i just was wondering should it be considered to the lack of storage or its something wrong with my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 GB of free memory (what you have) is good enough for any small or mid-sized app to perform alright. Problems may occur it the app is highly resource intensive and has a lot of run-time graphics load/unload. You should try checking and optimizing your app if it falls under the first category.

Here are a few official performance tips that might help you: [[Link]](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

> - Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects
> - Prefer Static Over Virtual
> - Use Static Final For Constants
> - Avoid Internal Getters/Setters
> - Use Enhanced For Loop Syntax
> - Consider Package Instead of Private Access with Private Inner Classes
> - Avoid Using Floating-Point
> - Know and Use the Libraries
> - Use Native Methods Carefully
> - Use Native Methods Judiciously

Comment: so that means that low storage memory anyway affects the app performance right?

Comment: yes in extreme cases it will obviously affect, but i think 2 GB is good enough free space for small and mid sized apps.